# Plotting profile likelihood curves in R

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to plot the profile likelihood curve of a GLM
parameter with 95% pLCI's on the same plot.  The example I have been trying
with is below.  The plots I am getting are not the likelihood curves that I
was expecting.  The y-axis of the plots is tau and I would like that axis
to be the likelihood so that I have a curve that maxes at the parameter
estimate.  I am not sure where I find those likelihood values?  I may just
be misinterpreting the theory behind this. Thanks for any help you can give.

Max

```
clotting <- data.frame(
u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18),
lot2 = c(69,35,26,21,18,16,13,12,12))
glm2<-glm(lot2 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family=Gamma)
prof<-profile(glm2)
plot(prof)
```

Comment: You never stored the results of your call to glm here.

Comment: Don't know how that did not copy over, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regenerate your example:

```
clotting <- data.frame(
                       u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
                       lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18),
                       lot2 = c(69,35,26,21,18,16,13,12,12))
glm2 <- glm(lot2 ~ log(u), data=clotting, family=Gamma)
```

The `profile.glm` function actually lives in the `MASS` package:

```
library(MASS)
prof<-profile(glm2)
```

In order to figure out what `profile.glm` and `plot.profile` are doing, see `?profile.glm` and `?plot.profile`. However, in order to dig into the `profile` object it may also be useful to examine the code of `MASS:::profile.glm` and `MASS:::plot.profile` ... basically, what these tell you is that `profile` is returning the *signed square root* of the difference between the deviance and the minimum deviance, scaled by the dispersion parameter.  The reason that this is done is so that the profile for a perfectly quadratic profile will appear as a straight line (it's much easier to detect deviations from a straight line than from a parabola by eye).

The other thing that may be useful to know is how the profile is stored. Basically, it's a list of data frames (one for each parameter profiled), except that the individual data frames are a little bit weird (containing one vector component and one matrix component).

```
> str(prof)
List of 2
 $ (Intercept):'data.frame':    12 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ tau     : num [1:12] -3.557 -2.836 -2.12 -1.409 -0.702 ...
  ..$ par.vals: num [1:12, 1:2] -0.0286 -0.0276 -0.0267 -0.0258 -0.0248 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "log(u)"
  ..$ dev     : num [1:12] 0.00622 0.00753 0.00883 0.01012 0.0114 ...
 $ log(u)     :'data.frame':    12 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ tau     : num [1:12] -3.516 -2.811 -2.106 -1.403 -0.701 ...
  ..$ par.vals: num [1:12, 1:2] -0.0195 -0.0204 -0.0213 -0.0222 -0.023 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
```

It also contains attributes `summary` and `original.fit` that you can use to recover the dispersion and minimum deviance:

```
disp <- attr(prof,"summary")$dispersion
mindev <- attr(prof,"original.fit")$deviance
```

Now reverse the transformation for parameter 1:

```
dev1 <- prof[[1]]$tau^2
dev2 <- dev1*disp+mindev
```

Plot:

```
plot(prof[[1]][,1],dev2,type="b")
```

(This is the plot of the deviance.  You can multiply by 0.5 to get the negative log-likelihood, or -0.5 to get the log-likelihood ...)

**edit**: some more general functions to transform the profile into a useful format for `lattice`/`ggplot` plotting ...

```
tmpf <- function(x,n) {
    data.frame(par=n,tau=x$tau,
               deviance=x$tau^2*disp+mindev,
               x$par.vals,check.names=FALSE)
}
pp <- do.call(rbind,mapply(tmpf,prof,names(prof),SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
library(reshape2)
pp2 <- melt(pp,id.var=1:3)
pp3 <- subset(pp2,par==variable,select=-variable)
```

Now plot it with lattice:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(deviance~value|par,type="b",data=pp3,
       scales=list(x=list(relation="free")))
```

[image]

Or with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pp3,aes(value,deviance))+geom_line()+geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~par,scale="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: N.B., I think tau has been changed to z in more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, for fun, I took the above and whipped it together into a single function using `purrr::imap_dfr` as I couldn't find a package that implements the above.

```
get_profile_glm <- function(aglm){
  prof <- MASS:::profile.glm(aglm)
  disp <- attr(prof,"summary")$dispersion

  purrr::imap_dfr(prof, .f = ~data.frame(par = .y,
                                deviance=.x$z^2*disp+aglm$deviance, 
                                values = as.data.frame(.x$par.vals)[[.y]],
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

}
```

Works great!

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())

ggplot(get_profile_glm(aglm), aes(x = values, y = deviance)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~par, scale = "free_x")
```

[image]