# How to increase the number of values returned by R MASS::profile?

Tags: r, log-likelihood

The short question is: *profile() returns 12 parameter values. How can it be made to return a greater number?*

The motivation for my question is to reproduce Fig. 1.3 in *Applied Logistic Regression 3rd Edition* by David W. Hosmer Jr., Stanley Lemeshow and Rodney X. Sturdivant (2009), which plots the **profile log likelihood** against the coefficient for x = age over the confint() interval.

[image: Figure 1.3 of HLS]

The glm model was

```
fit <- glm(chd ~ age, data = chdage, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

which relates the presence or absence of coronary heart disease to age for 100 patients. The results of the model agree with Table 1.3 in the text on p. 10.

For convenience, a csv file of the data is in [my gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/technocrat/eb2b168e3c63871ac9c119c60bd695e1/raw/992b806a71d2997d69f32893c024fdaa544e97bb/chdage.csv)

Using the guidance provided by [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker%20in%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916139/plotting-profile-likelihood-curves-in-r) for multiplying MASS::profile's output of deviance by -0.5 to convert to negative log-likelihood in [a 2011 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916139/plotting-profile-likelihood-curves-in-r) using the tidy function provided by [jebyrnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190352/jebyrnes) in later comment on the same post.

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
library(purrr)

get_profile_glm <- function(aglm){
  prof <- MASS:::profile.glm(aglm)
  disp <- attr(prof,"summary")$dispersion

  purrr::imap_dfr(prof, .f = ~data.frame(par = .y,
                                deviance=.x$z^2*disp+aglm$deviance, 
                                values = as.data.frame(.x$par.vals)[[.y]],
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

}

pll <- get_profile_glm(fit) %>% filter(par == "age") %>% mutate(beta = values) %>% mutate(pll = deviance * -0.5) %>% select(-c(par,values, deviance))

pll

> pll
      beta    pll
1  0.04895 -57.70
2  0.06134 -56.16
3  0.07374 -55.02
4  0.08613 -54.25
5  0.09853 -53.81
6  0.11092 -53.68
7  0.12332 -53.80
8  0.13571 -54.17
9  0.14811 -54.74
10 0.16050 -55.49
11 0.17290 -56.41
12 0.18529 -57.47
```

This can be plotted to obtain an approximation of the HLS figure 1.3 with the ablines for the alpha = 0.95 interval from

```
confint(fit)
```

and

```
logLik(fit)
```

The asymmetry in the legend can be calculated with

```
asymmetry <- function(x) {
    ci <- confint(x, level = 0.95)
    ci_lower <- ci[2,1]
    ci_upper <- ci[2,2]
    coeff <- x$coefficients[2]
    round(100 * ((ci_upper - coeff) - (coeff - ci_lower))/(ci_upper - ci_lower), 2)
}

asym <- assymetry(fit)
```

The plot is produced with

```
ggplot(data = pll, aes(x = beta, y = pll)) + 
geom_line() + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.06, 0.08, 0.10, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-57, -56, -55, -54)) + 
xlab("Coefficient for age") + 
ylab("Profile log-likelihood function") + 
geom_vline(xintercept = confint(fit)[2,1]) + 
geom_vline(xintercept = confint(fit)[2,2]) + 
geom_hline(yintercept = (logLik(fit) - (qchisq(0.95, df = 1)/2))) + 
theme_classic() + 
ggtitle(paste("Asymmetry =", scales::percent(asym/100, accuracy = 0.1))) + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: Plot requiring adjustment]

Two adjustments are needed:

1. The curve should be smoothed by the addition of beta values and log likelihood values along the x and y axes, respectively.
2. The range of beta should be set comparably to approximately [0.0575,0.1625] (visually, from the figure). I assume this can be done by subsetting as required.

A note regarding the logLik y intercept on the figure. It appears to be based on a transposed value of log-likelihood. See Table 1-3 at p. 10, where it is given as -53.676546, compared to the equation on p. 19 where it is transposed to -53.6756.

Comment: You can see the code of `profile.glm` by typing `getAnywhere(profile.glm)` and then you will be able to answer yourself

Comment: Thanks, I did look, but failed to identify the argument that would change the output.

Comment: Thanks, again. Taking another cue from Ben Bolker, the `del` argument to `profile` defaults to return around 10, changing both it and `maxsteps` gets me there. I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to prompting from [kjetil b halvorsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469680/kjetil-b-halvorsen) and the comment by [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) in the [bbmle package vignette for mle2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/vignettes/mle2.pdf)

> – del Step size (scaled by standard error) (Default: zmax/5.) Presum- ably (?) copied from MASS::profile.glm, which says (in ?profile.glm): “[d]efault value chosen to allow profiling at about 10 parameter values.”

I "solved" my issue with a change to the `get_profile_glm` function in the original post:

```
prof <- MASS:::profile.glm(aglm, del = .05, maxsteps = 52)
```

which yielded 100 points and produced the plot I was hoping for:

[image: Figure 1.3]

I say *"solved*" because the values hardwired were determined by trial and error. But it must do for now.